# Creating Sparse Array in Python

Tags: python

I need to create a sparse array something like:

```
diff = []
for letter , arr in hashmap.items():
    for hashval in arr:
        diff[ inp_hash -  hashval ]  = letter
```

How to use this feature in Python just like that of Javascript or PHP? How to loop to find an element in array?
All I find is using some library or the other. I want without using any library like Numpy

Comment: Will a dictionary work?

Comment: no i need something like this  [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch07s03.html)

Comment: OK, and why wouldn't a dictionary work?

Comment: I've been conditioned to use array for it due to performance in C++, Javascript, PHP etc. Secondly these array indexes will be in increasing order. Hasmap keys are in random order though we can still sort them. Any specific reason to use a map(dictionary) here when a sparse array may work?

Comment: That's a bit like asking if there's any particular reason to use a spade, when digging will work. A spade is a way to dig, and a dictionary is a way to implement a sparse array. Dictionaries (i.e. hashtables) are used to implement sparse arrays precisely because they can do reads and writes in O(1) time. If it's particularly important to be able to iterate over the non-zero entries in order of index, you can use a [SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/), but then the basic read/write operations won't be O(1).